# Format code in Razor section visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, razor, format

I have project ASP.NET MVC in Visual Studio 2017 (Enterprise edition)
In my Layout Page I have three sections

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        if(checkUserHaveMobilePhone) {
             @RenderSection("ScriptsPhone", false)
        }
        else {
             @RenderSection("ScriptsPC", false)
        }           
        @RenderSection("Scripts", false)

    });
</script>
```

And in any View I have this code (and this work)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@section Scripts {
    $(window).resize(function () {

    });
}   
</script>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NklBQ.jpg

But when I add if-statement Section don't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@section Scripts {

    $(window).resize(function () {
        if (parseInt($(window).width()) <= 800) {
            alert("Alert");
        }
    });

}   
</script>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz4cT.jpg

After this I get syntax error

> Expected character '}'

Comment: What do you mean "don't work". Are there any errors? What is your expected result? What is the output?

Comment: Try with `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`

Comment: Changing `parseFloat` from `parseInt` has given nothing, this code works in a simple HTML file

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@section Scripts {
<text>
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if (parseInt($(window).width()) <= 800) {
            alert("Alert");
        }
    });
</text>
}   
</script>
```

Try it with Text tag, it should be working.

Comment: With text tag does not work and JavaScript syntax highlighting is disabled

Comment: @thebox is it possbile for you to put script tag inside section tag?

Comment: Yes, but after put script tag inside section tag I get Javascript syntax error because I have after this script tag from View inside script tag from LayoutPage